# Time difference between 2 timespans fails to return expected data

Tags: c#, timespan

I have created 2 Timespans below:

```
TimeSpan currentTs = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(43995); //12:13:15
TimeSpan towTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(303072); //12:11:12
```

I'm trying to find the difference in minutes (by the seconds I'm passing it, it looks like they are on different days).  I am hoping for around 2 minutes difference, but in reality, I'm getting -57 minutes.

```
int timeDifference = (int)currentTs.Subtract(towTime).Minutes;
```

Can someone explain what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are just looking for the difference between the minutes (not including the days, hours or seconds), then you can use

```
double timeDifference = currentTs.Minutes - towTime.Minutes; // 2
```

This is just the difference of the minutes component though.  As other people have said, these times are separated by 3 days, so a TimeSpan possibly isn't ideal.

Or, If you want the seconds to be included as well, you can use

```
TimeSpan minutes1 = new TimeSpan (0, currentTs.Minutes, currentTs.Seconds);
TimeSpan minutes2 = new TimeSpan (0, towTime.Minutes, towTime.Seconds);

double timeDifference = minutes1.TotalMinutes - minutes2.TotalMinutes // 2.05;
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the info.  I'll check on why the times vary by so many days.  In theory, they should be the same day, but who knows.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the `TotalMinutes` property not `Minutes` - the later is just the minutes part of the time difference, the former is the full time difference expressed in fractional minutes:

```
double timeDifference = currentTs.Subtract(towTime).TotalMinutes;
```

Also easier to read is:

```
double timeDifference = (currentTs - towTime).TotalMinutes;
```

Comment: If i do total minutes, it has me as -4317
int timeDifference = (int)currentTs.Subtract(towTime).TotalMinutes;

Comment: @Jason that is the time difference, if you look at what you are passing in, are you sure you are not looking for `DateTime` if you want to compare time on different days?

Comment: @Jason: 43995 - 303072 = -259077, -259077/60 = -4317.95

Comment: I guess that is what i am unsure of.  I was hoping that it would look at the difference in minutes, not taking in account the days.  Like i said in my orig, for those 2 times, i was hoping for a difference of around 2 minutes.  Can you show me what i should be doing?  I will be out for the rest of the day.  WIll reply back early tomorrow

Comment: @Jason See Bodrick's answer, that sounds like what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you want to completely ignore the fact that the times are different by about 3 days.  In that case, if you take the remainder after division by 86400 (the number of seconds in a day) and pass that to TimeSpan.FromSeconds, you should hopefully get what you want:

```
TimeSpan currentTs = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(43995 % 86400); //12:13:15
TimeSpan towTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(303072 % 86400); //12:11:12, ignoring the 3 days.
double timeDifference = (currentTs - towTime).TotalMinutes;
```

I got the value of `timeDifference` as 2.05 when I tried this.

Of course, if `currentTs` is earlier in the day than `towTime` (perhaps because midnight falls between them), the time difference will come out negative.  If you still want to count the number of minutes between the two, assuming that `currentTs` is always after `towTime`, then you'll need to add 1440 (the number of minutes in a day) to `timeDifference` if it works out negative:

```
if (timeDifference < 0)
{
    timeDifference += 1440;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the second timespan isn't 12:11:12, its 3:12:11:12.

So you're going to get a negative result which would be in the thousands if you did total minutes (since its representing something like -2days, 57 minutes, 57 seconds)...since you just ask for Minutes and not TotalMinutes you just get the -57.

Answer (score 0):

currentTime is less then towTime (you seem to be missing one digit).

Comment: The values i am passing in are correct.  That is exactly what my program is looking at.